# PoolableConnectionFactory Invalid handle

Tags: java, tomcat

I'm deploying an old app on a new box.  When hitting the database for the first time I get

```
File input error: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Invalid handle)
```

I've set up my resource in context.xml, my dsn with unixODBC, and my resource-ref in web.xml.  What else am I missing?

```
from content.xml -->

<Resource name="jdbc/MoleComp" auth="Container"
type="javax.sql.DataSource" maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="-1"
removeAbandoned="false" removeAbandonedTimeout="60"
username="userName" password="passWord" 
driverClassName="sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver" 
url="jdbc:odbc:DSNName"/>

from app/WEB-INF/web.xml -->

<resource-ref>
    <description>DB connection</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/MoleComp</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting this problem on yet another server, I switched the application from using unixODBC and odbc.jdbc to java type 4 driver [jTDS](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/) jtds.jdbc.  Performance is a bit better too!

Answer (score 0):

First, you should remove the <resource-def> from web.xml. This is just another way to define data source, which you've already done in context.xml.

That error is from ODBC-JDBC bridge driver. So either ODBC is not running or the `url="jdbc:odbc:DSNName"` is invalid.

Comment: Thanks Zhihong.  It is a valid DSN, I can connect to it from the shell with isql (provided with unixODB).  If I give it an invalid DSN, I get "Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory ([unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified)"

Comment: Oh, and I remove the <resource-ref> from web.xml, still get the same error.

Comment: I have no experience with unixODB. It must be some kind of environment  difference causing it work in isql, not in Java.